# На чем написана tilda?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, конструктор, tilda

задаюсь вопросом- на каких языках написан такой конструктор сайтов как **Tilda**? И так же интересно, как вообще пишут конструкторы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> на каких языках написан такой конструктор сайтов как Tilda

В википедии не было написано, поэтому:

- Пошел на сайт https://tilda.cc/ru/
- Пролистал вниз сайта и открыл вакансии https://company.tilda.cc/ru/
- Посмотрел кого ищут на бэк и фронт

Требования на бэке:

> Отличные знания и навыки разработки на PHP; Знания и навыки
> использования MySQL; Базовые знания HTML, CSS, JS/JQuery;

Требования на фронте:

> Отличные знания HTML, CSS, JS;
> Знания фреймворков Vue/React ;

Comment: Если на фронте Vue/React, то зачем бэкендеру JQuery? 

Comment: @andreymal, у меня такой же вопрос был :D Мб, ранее фронт на другом был, а требования не обновили :)

Comment: Обычно на бэкенд ищут людей, которые понимают, что происходит на фронте хоть немного. Поэтому знание или js, или jquery. Тут сильно никто не будет на конкретные знания смотреть, скорее общее представление.

Comment: jQuery вполне может использоваться бэкенд разработчиками в какой-нибудь административной панели...